# Iterate through a String array and assign the value to Worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA, so pardon for any silly mistakes.

I have the names of my worksheets in an array. I am trying to go to each of the worksheets in the array by using the following:

```
Set ws = Worksheets(listBoxValuesArray(arrayIndex))
```

But I get the error message saying "Subscript out of Range"

I also tried this:

```
Sheets.Select (listBoxValuesArray(arrayIndex))
```

When I print the `listBoxValuesArray(arrayIndex)` I am getting the values

Here is the complete for loop

```
Dim arraySize As Integer
arraySize = jobSheetsDisplay.ListCount
Dim listBoxValuesArray() As Variant
Dim listBoxArrayIndex As Integer
Dim arrayValue As Variant
Dim listBoxIndex As Integer
Dim arrayIndex As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
ReDim listBoxValuesArray(arraySize)
listBoxArrayIndex = 0
For listBoxIndex = 0 To jobSheetsDisplay.ListCount - 1
    If jobSheetsDisplay.Selected(listBoxIndex) Then
    listBoxValuesArray(listBoxArrayIndex) = CStr(jobSheetsDisplay.List(listBoxIndex))
    listBoxArrayIndex = listBoxArrayIndex + 1
   End If
Next listBoxIndex
For arrayIndex = 0 To UBound(listBoxValuesArray) 
Set ws = Worksheets(listBoxValuesArray(arrayIndex)) '
MsgBox (listBoxValuesArray(arrayIndex))
Next arrayIndex
```

Basically, I get the values into the array from a list box in a form. The array is defined as a variant type and so is the array index.

Thanks for any help

Comment: show more code please, it should work if `listBoxValuesArray(arrayIndex)` returns _existing_ sheet name. Also if you ahve multiply workbooks opened when macro runs, try `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(listBoxValuesArray(arrayIndex))`

Comment: What value do you use for `arrayIndex`? The error can happen when either the `arrayIndex` is too large or too small for the `listBoxValuesArray`, or when the name doesn't match the name of a worksheet. Maybe you need to reference the correct workbook: `Workbooks(workbookName).Worksheets(sheetName)`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am using Integer for arrayIndex.

Comment: are you sure that `listBoxValuesArray(arrayIndex)` returns correct sheet name? check additional spaces (trailing/leading)

Comment: I posted the complete code above. I think I am doing something wrong while allocating the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Set** command works fine for me in this context:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim listBoxValuesArray(1 To 3) As String
    For i = 1 To 3
        listBoxValuesArray(i) = Worksheets(i).Name
    Next i

    arrayIndex = 2
    Set ws = Worksheets(listBoxValuesArray(arrayIndex))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, the point is that the size of listBoxValuesArray changes depending on the how many values the user has selected. That is why I have not specified the size initially

Comment: @Rst  You are correct!  The size of the array can be dynamic, but the size should not exceed the number of worksheets, the array must be properly filled before items can be retrieved, and the value of the index must be properly set.............once you have met the prerequisite conditions, your **Set** command should work.